# How to change the number within an element ID upon each click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a 7 divs and 1 "Next" button, where I'm trying to come up with a solution so each time the "Next" button is clicked, the current div slides up and the next div slides down. At the end, it would go back to the 1st div.

HTML:

```
<div id='selection_1'>selection_1</div>

<div id='selection_2' style='display:none'>selection_2</div>

<div id='selection_3' style='display:none'>selection_3</div>

<div id='selection_4' style='display:none'>selection_4</div>

......

<div id='selection_7' style='display:none'>selection_7</div>

<button type='button'>Next</button>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
 $("#next").click(function () {
          $('#selection_1').slideUp();
          $('#selection_2').slideDown();
    });
});
```

But I got stuck since it only can only work once. I can't click next again to get selection_3 to show up, not to mention having it return to selection 1 when a round is finished.

I'm pretty new to JQuery so any advice is appreciated!

Comment: You need something like this **[jQuery Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)**

Comment: Use a variable to keep track of which DIV is the current one, and increment it each time you click.

Comment: JQuery UI elements such as JQuery according would be nice, except my users, who often use cheap Android phones, repeatedly reported browser crashing loading pages with jQuery UI...:(

Answer (score 3):

Store index in some global variable and use it to generate id, also assign id to next button

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ntvM5/3/)**

```
$(function(){
   currentNum = 1;
   $("#selection_1").show();
   $("#next").click(function () {
      $('#selection_' + currentNum).slideUp();
       if (currentNum > 7) currentNum = 0;
      $('#selection_' + (currentNum+1)).slideDown();
      currentNum++;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this function it may help you

```
 $(function(){
        var count=1;
        $("#next").click(function () {
              $('#selection_'+count).slideUp();
              $('#selection_'+(count+1)).slideDown();
                 count+= 1;
              if(count==7){
                   count=1;
            }
       });
  });
```

Comment: Nice one. Although for some reason selection 7 would not hide itself when selection 1 appears

Answer (score 0):

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/zG3RQ/1/)**.

```
$(function(){
    var current = 1;
    $('div[id^="sel"] div').hide();
    $('#selection_1 div').slideDown();
    $("#next").click(function () {
        current++;
        $('#selection_'+(current-1)+' div').slideUp();
        $('#selection_'+current+' div').slideDown();
    });
});
```

At start, Display just 1st `<div>`, and keep on incrementing the number on click of next.

Comment: Nice one. Although for some reason selection 7 would not hide itself when selection 1 appears

Comment: why? It works for me in the fiddle. Do you want it to hide or no?

Comment: Ah sorry! I actually modified my html code a bit before testing your code: I added "style='display:none;" for all selections except selection 1, because I actually wanted to hide all non-active divs by default. Somehow it is not showing properly then.